# Redirect to Different library using content organizer rules in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, drop-off-library, content-organizer-rule

I uploaded a document & its metadata using Rest API to the "Drop OFF" library with content organizer rules which is set to redirect document from Drop off to different library.
Document uploaded & metadata update works fine but the redirection of document by content organizer rules to different library not working.
When I try to upload the document directly from SharePoint UI OOB, it works fine and document redirect to the right library.

So I am not able to understand what makes upload the document using rest API not redirecting the document.

Answer (score 0):

To move document from one document library to another, you need to create content organizer rules on both libraries.

Users are redirected to the Drop Off Library when they try to upload content to libraries in this site that have one or more content organizer rules pointing to them.  So that means only after you create a content organizer rule point to the document library, the documents will be redirected to the drop off library.

Eg: you have LibraryA, LibraryB, Drop Off Library.

If you want to move the documents from LibraryA to LibraryB, you must create an content orgainizer rule pointing to LibraryB and also create an content orgainizer rule pointing to LibraryA.